# How to reduce the time and space complexity of the function foo(n)?

Tags: python, time, big-o

The time complexity for the foo function is O(n^2) but i need to reduce it and cant seem to figure it out.

```
def bar ( n ):
    if n == 0 :
        return 0
    else :
        return n + bar ( n - 1 )

def foo ( n ):
    if n == 0 :
        return 0
    else :
        return bar ( n ) + foo ( n - 1 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve `bar` like this:

```
def bar(n):
    return n * (n + 1) / 2
```

This should cut `foo` to a O(n).

You can even define `foo` as:

```
def foo(n):
    return n * (n + 1) / 4 + n * (2 * n + 1) * (n + 1) / 12
```

To have a function in O(1) :)

Comment: Can you explain the last term?  `n * (2 * n + 1) * (n + 1) / 12`

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Sums_of_powers

Comment: why the division of both members by 2?

Comment: Because you're doing sum(sum i)) = sum i * (i + 1) / 2 = 1 / 2 * [ sum i + sum i² ]

Comment: we have bar = sum (n); foo = n (sum n) = sum (n2); foo + bar = (n+1) (sum n) = sum n2 + sum n = sum (n2 + n) = sum (n)(n+1) . I don't really get the factor 1/2...

Comment: That's not what foo does, foo does: foo(n) = sum_i^n ( sum_j^i j ) = sum_i^n ( i * (i + 1) / 2 ) = 1 / 2 * [ sum_i^n i + sum_i^n i² ]